# Setting up SSL with Elastic Beanstalk: How to fix ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID?

Tags: ssl, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a website, example.com, that has a subdomain called play.example.com which hosts a multiplayer game on it.

Separately, I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment that hosts the game server (NodeJs backend), separate from the client build itself.

play.example.com connects to the game server over https, but is met with the error: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

Steps I have taken:

1) Created an SSL certificate for *.example.com using AWS Certificate Manager

2) Added a listener to my load balancer that listens on port 443

3) Created an alias, type A IPv4 with the name play.example.com to the EB url

I understand the the error means that there is a name mismatch between the URL and the certificate, but isn't that what the alias is supposed to fix?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've spent about a week now trying to fix these issues myself, and unfortunately Stackoverflow is full of people asking this question and nobody's giving answers.

Here's how I solved it, some of this might work for you too. It ended up being primarily configuration issues.

Your SSL cert is appropriate - I ended up hardcoding my subdomain `ops.example.com` but your wildcard shouldn't be an issue.

I read somewhere that AWS requires any DNS records to be of type CNAME, so I set up a basic CNAME record to redirect `ops` to `my-site.my-aws-region-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

Then, what ended up being the linchpin to the whole thing was that in order to make HTTPS work, your load balancer has to be Listening for HTTPS on 443 and route to the instance via HTTP on 80.

Amazon was trying to tell me this, but because I was a noob and because their tutorials are some of the worst tutorials I've read in my entire career, they actually don't expose any of your secure ports to the internet. Which is actually fine because your traffic is encrypted all the way up to the load balancer, and then after that, even though it's not HTTPS anymore, it's all already on amazon's servers anyway so it's not any less secure.

Hope something in here helps!